# run docker-compose command in crontab

Tags: bash, docker-compose, cron

I have a `docker-compose.yml` and `.env` and same location.The `.env` file hold environment variable of `docker-compose.yml` file.I want to run `docker-compose exec` command in `crontab` but I get some error because of missing `.env` file.I used `--env-file` option for `docker-compose` command then I get `the input device is not a TTY` error.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `docker-compose exec` you have to user `-T` option.

```
Options:
    -d, --detach      Detached mode: Run command in the background.
    --privileged      Give extended privileges to the process.
    -u, --user USER   Run the command as this user.
    -T                Disable pseudo-tty allocation. By default `docker-compose exec`
                      allocates a TTY.
    --index=index     index of the container if there are multiple
                      instances of a service [default: 1]
    -e, --env KEY=VAL Set environment variables (can be used multiple times,
                      not supported in API < 1.25)
    -w, --workdir DIR Path to workdir directory for this command.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `docker-compose exec -T` to prevent allocate a `tty` by `docker-compose`.

`docker-compose` allocate `tty` by default.